# Preflight request failing on calling a POST request with keepalive using fetch api

Tags: api, fetch-api, preflight

I am getting an error `Preflight request for request with keepalive specified is currently not supported` on calling a POST request using the fetch api with `keepalive` enabled. Any help would be appreciated . I am calling this api on `beforeunload` event.

API Request

```
  fetch(uri, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': options.headers.get('content-type'),
      'Authorization': options.headers.get('authorization')
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(interactionBody),
    keepalive: true
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=835821

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround until [the Chrome issue fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=835821)

it working when using `mode: 'same-origin'`

```
fetch(uri, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': options.headers.get('content-type'),
    'Authorization': options.headers.get('authorization')
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(interactionBody),
  mode: 'same-origin',
  keepalive: true
})
```